# Makefile compilation issue with javac

Tags: java, makefile, compilation

I have a problem with a makefile. I have three classes. They do pretty simple stuff. One does an addition on a subtraction, and the last one will instantiate the two and simply print the resulted addition and subtraction.

Now when I create my makefile, I compile my Plus.java and my Minus.java but don't know how to compile the main class because it depends on the previous two. I want to compile and run it from the makefile if it's possible.

I get the above results when I try to run make:

```
javac -g Plus.class Minus.class
javac: invalid flag: Plus.class
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make: *** [Operation.class] Error 2
```

I don't know how to proceed; please forgive me if my question is to simple but I am new working with these stuff. I've searched many sites but with no answer.

Here is my Makefile:

```
JCC = javac

JCR = java

JFLAGS = -g

default: Operation.class

Plus.class: Plus.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Plus.java

Minus.class: Minus.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Minus.java

Operation.class: Operation.class
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Operation.class  

run: Operation.class
    $(JCR) Operation.class

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: don't use makefile for java. Use ant or maven.

Comment: I wanted to use makefiles because I have to work with java and c++ files also.

Comment: I know makefiles, but not java. I don't see how this makefile could work, or how it could give this error. Are you simply running `make`, or do you give it a target, like `make Pluss.class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was a problem with the packages. I edited my files in netbeans and remained:

package operations

to every one of them

so I got Operation to compile but now it didn't run

Silly problem....

```
JCC = javac

JCR = java

JFLAGS = -g

default: Operation.class Plus.class Minus.class

Plus.class: Plus.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Plus.java

Minus.class: Minus.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Minus.java

Operation.class: Operation.java Plus.java Minus.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Operation.java  Plus.java Minus.java

run:
    $(JCR) Operation

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: Try formatting your `Makefile` as code using the `101` button.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the names of source files to javac:

```
javac -g Plus.java
```

A better option is possibly:

```
javac -g *.java
```

Very few people in the Java world invoke javac directly or use makefiles. Most people use an IDE when developing:

Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org
Netbeans: http://www.netbeans.org

And then a more comprehensive build tool for final / automated builds:

Ant: http://ant.apache.org/
Maven: http://maven.apache.org/

Both of those could be invoked from make, or indeed invoke make themselves, in order to integrate with your existing build system.

EDIT:
It seems you have a makefile issue. See if this works:

```
JCC = javac
JCR = java
JFLAGS = -g

all:
[TAB]$(JCC) $(JFLAGS) *.java

run:
[TAB]$(JCR) Operation

clean:
[TAB]$(RM) *.class
```

Replace [TAB] with an actual tab character - as you probably know this is incredibly important in make!

Comment: Thats the thing. I am currently working on a project that I do have to us these things and not the IDE's.

Comment: Thank you but the tab is there. It just didn't show up in the post

Comment: +1 for `ant`, although using `make` this way can be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run javac -g Plus.java Minus.java   (not .class)

Comment: I don't think I understand. I show you my makefile instead maybe I cand find out this way:

JCC = javac

JCR = java

JFLAGS = -g

default: Operation.class

Plus.class: Plus.java
 $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Plus.java

Minus.class: Minus.java
 $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Minus.java

Operation.class: Operation.class
 $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Operation.class  

run: Operation.class
 $(JCR) Operation.class
 
clean:
 $(RM) *.class

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Alas, managing Java class dependencies is a pain using make (been there done that in relatively large projects), so you should still seriously consider using Ant or some other appropriate tool.

```
JCC = javac

JCR = java

JFLAGS = -g

default: Operation.class

Plus.class: Plus.java
            $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Plus.java

Minus.class: Minus.java
             $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Minus.java

Operation.class: Operation.java Plus.class Minus.class
                $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Operation.java 

run: Operation.class
    $(JCR) Operation.class

clean: $(RM) *.class
```